# Multiple saves with one submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-forms

I need a form that includes 1 radio button, 1 submit button and a checkbox for each listed item.

Upon submit, the form should save a separate record for each checked item.  Each saved item should include the value of the radio button along with other hidden values.

The form renders but crashes upon submit. The error message is:

```
undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x007fb4b3b1a520>
```

My code is:

```
     <%= form_tag(controller: "handoffs", action: "create", method: "post") %>
            <%= radio_button_tag(:attend, "arrive") %>
            <%= label(:handoff_arrive, "drop-off") %>
            <%= radio_button_tag(:attend, "depart") %>
            <%= label(:handoff_depart, "pick-up") %>

            <% @parent.children.each do |child| %>
                <%= check_box_tag "handoff[][check]" %>
                <strong>
                <%= child.fname %>
                <%= child.mname %>
                <%= child.lname %>
                </strong><br>

                <% group = Group.find(child.group_id) %>

                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][attend]" %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][group_name]", :value => group.name %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][child_id]", :value => child.id %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][center_id]", :value => @center.id %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][escort_fname]", :value => @parent.fname %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][escort_lname]", :value => @parent.lname %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][child_fname]", :value => child.fname %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][child_mname]", :value => child.mname %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "handoff[][child_lname]", :value => child.lname %>
            <% end %>
            <%= button_to :submit, :class => 'f_submit' %>
        <% end %>
```

Controller actions:

```
def new
    @handoff = Handoff.new
    @parent = current_parent
    @center = Center.find(@parent.center_id)
  end

  def create
    params["handoff"].each do |handoff|
      if params[:handoff["check"]] != ""
      @handoff = Handoff.new(handoff_params)
      @handoff.save
      end
    end
  end

  def handoff_params

    params.require(:handoff).permit(:attend, :group_name, :child_id, :center_id, :escort_fname, :escort_lname, :child_fname, :child_mname, :child_lname)
  end
```

Request parameters (in error report)

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"snqrS130bXNV4bmMHOMlXeyhX2rWFVpmY/PYIv0jn97MBOLSWWw2jBbeYGPyjt7O9l5pRVNuFiu1qOwkGpELTA==",
"attend"=>"depart", "handoff"=>[{"check"=>"1", "attend"=>"",
"group_name"=>"{:value=>\"Gifted\"}", "child_id"=>"{:value=>60}",
"center_id"=>"{:value=>4}", "escort_fname"=>"{:value=>\"Richard\"}",
"escort_lname"=>"{:value=>\"Messing\"}",
"child_fname"=>"{:value=>\"Aaron\"}",
"child_mname"=>"{:value=>\"Lawrence\"}",
"child_lname"=>"{:value=>\"Schwartz\"}"}, {"check"=>"1", "attend"=>"",
"group_name"=>"{:value=>\"Arts & Crafts\"}",
"child_id"=>"{:value=>61}", "center_id"=>"{:value=>4}",
"escort_fname"=>"{:value=>\"Richard\"}",
"escort_lname"=>"{:value=>\"Messing\"}",
"child_fname"=>"{:value=>\"Joseph\"}",
"child_mname"=>"{:value=>\"Michael\"}",
"child_lname"=>"{:value=>\"Messing\"}"}], "method"=>"post",
"controller"=>"handoffs", "action"=>"create"}
```

Comment: I solved the problem.  Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case. First you need to create array with all values that you would like to export I used helper to do that. I'll show you my example:

```
def get_table_of_keywords(keywords)
    exact_keywords = []
    keyword_array.each do |key|
      if !key.blank?
        exact_keywords << {keyword: key, created_at: DateTime.now.in_time_zone, updated_at: DateTime.now.in_time_zone }
      end
    end
  exact_keywords
  end
```

And the you are using **create**:

```
@inserted_keywords = @campaign.keywords.create(get_table_of_keywords(params[:keyword][:keyword])) # add new keywords to the list
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I have [] brackets in the form field_tags (handoff[]...) in order to create an array of hashes in params.  The error report shows that the array is being created.  But I don't think my code in the create action is accessing the array correctly.  And I don't understand why I'm getting the error:  'undefined method permit'.